# Is it possible to use SOS with a .NET7 AOT application?

Tags: .net-core, windbg, sos, aot

When building a .NET Core AOT application the necessary CLR functionality is, if I understand it correctly, statically linked into the executable. That means that at run time, `coreclr.dll` is not present as a module and consequently SOS complains that it cannot find a suitable runtime module.

I've tried specifying the extension and CLR path. I can load SOS that way, but so far I haven't been able to run any of the SOS extension commands against an AOT application.

My assumption is that the application still uses the same internal structures such as the managed heap, so I am wondering how these can be debugged in a managed context using SOS (or something similar).